# finding repeating params in query using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a search query like

```
`const query = '?sortBy=recent&page=2&comments=true&sortBy=rating' // two repeating params 'sortBy'
```

How can I use regex for checking is there any repeating params ????

Comment: Does it have to be regex? You could use `Array.from(new URLSearchParams(query))` to get a 2D array of keys and values. Then you can group based on duplicate keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not recommended to use regex.

Try this

```js
const query = new URLSearchParams('?sortBy=recent&page=2&comments=true&sortBy=rating');

const keys = [...query.keys()]; // convert iterable to array
console.log(keys)

const unique = keys.length === new Set(keys).size; // return false if dupes found
console.log(unique);

// to get the dupe(s)

const dupes = keys.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) !== i)
console.log(dupes)
```

Comment: Code works fine. Your answer helped me a lot, thanks ))